# Does anyone know what is wrong with my YAML?

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation

I have recently started learning YAML to use with AWS CloudFormation. It is a part of a course I am doing. I have written my YAML but my stack gives something different to what is expected in the designer.

This is my YAML

```
Parameters: 
   EnvironmentName:
      Description: An environment name that is prefixed to resource names
      Type: String
      Default: DE-Extract
      
   VpcCIDR:
      Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for this VPC
      Type: String
      Default: 192.168.0.0/16
    
   DataCenterPublicSubnetCIDR:
      Description: Please enter the IP range (CIDR notation) for the public subnet in the first Availability Zone
      Type: String
      Default: 192.168.10.0/24
    
Resources:
   VPC:
      Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
      Properties:
         CidrBlock: 
            Ref: VpcCIDR
         EnableDnsSupport: 'true'
         EnableDnsHostnames: 'true'
         Tags:
           - Key: Name
             Value: 
                Ref: EnvironmentName

   InternetGateway:
      Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
      Properties:
         Tags:
            - Key: Name
              Value: 
                 Ref: EnvironmentName

   InternetGatewayAttachment:
      Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
      Properties:
         InternetGatewayId: InternetGateway
         VpcId: 
            Ref: VPC

   DataCenterPublicSubnet:
      Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
      Properties:
         VpcId: 
            Ref: VPC
         CidrBlock: 
            Ref: DataCenterPublicSubnetCIDR
         AvailabilityZone: !Select [0, !GetAZs '']
         MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
         Tags:
            - Key: Name
              Value: DE-Extract Data Center Subnet

   PublicRouteTable:
      Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
      Properties:
         VpcId: 
            Ref: VPC
         Tags:
          - Key: Name
            Value: DE-Extract Public Routes

   DefaultPublicRoute:
      Type: AWS::EC2::Route
      DependsOn: InternetGatewayAttachment
      Properties:
         RouteTableId: 
            Ref: PublicRouteTable
         DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
         GatewayId: 
            Ref: InternetGateway

   DataCenterPublicSubnetRouteTableAssociation:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
      Properties:        
         SubnetId: 
            Ref: DataCenterPublicSubnet
         RouteTableId: 
            Ref: PublicRouteTable 
 
   WindowsInstanceSG:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
      Properties:
         VpcId: 
            Ref: VPC
         GroupName: DE-Extract-WindowsInstanceSG
         GroupDescription: This group permits RDP access to an instance deployed within the public subnet of the VPC.
         SecurityGroupIngress:
            - IpProtocol: tcp
              CidrIp: 0.0.0/0
              FromPort: 3389
              ToPort: 3389
         Tags:
          - Key: Name
            Value: DE-Extract-WindowsInstanceSG

   FileServerSG:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
      Properties:
         VpcId: 
            Ref: VPC
         GroupName: DE-Extract-FileServerSG
         GroupDescription: is responsible for permitting ssh access to the data center's file server from an internal source within the VPC.
         SecurityGroupIngress:
            - IpProtocol: tcp
              CidrIp: 192.168.10.0/24
              FromPort: 22
              ToPort: 22  
         Tags:
            Key: Name
            Value: DE-Extract-FileServerSG

   FileGatewaySG:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
      Properties:
         VpcId: 
            Ref: VPC
         GroupName: DE-Extract-FileGatewaySG
         GroupDescription: This security group controls the access to the file gateway instance configured later on
         SecurityGroupIngress:
            - IpProtocol: tcp
              CidrIp: 192.168.0.0/16
              FromPort: 1
              ToPort: 65534
```

[This is what i am getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVHq7.png)
[This is what i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWLl4.png)

I am not too sure what is wrong, any form of direction would be much appreciated. I think theres an issue with the referencing (i was originally using !Ref and changed it to long form but nothng changed)

Comment: When developing an infrastructure with Cloudformation, it’s always a good idea to start small. Remove all but 2-3 resources from your stack, deploy them, see if they do what you need, then add the next one.

Comment: You forgot to explain what's wrong with the template. Any errors?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors it's just giving me the wrong thing in designer. for instance the public route table and the subnet are not inside the vpc, and there is no link from the public route table to the subnet

Comment: Forget the designer. Just deploy your stack and check what actually is happening.

Comment: i deployed the stack ( the CidrIp for the windowsSG was wrong, i fixed it) it deployed fine.